# How to highlight Python modules that are not used in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs, elisp, syntax-highlighting

Something like 6 months ago, I met a developer who was using Emacs. We were writing Django code and thus Python. There is a feature he has enabled (wrote himself ?) which could highlight the imported modules that were not used.

I am willing to have this, unfortunately I didn't find anything related the past 15 minutes. So my guess is that he wrote it himself. I am far from the Lisp guru you guys could be, hence here I am, asking for directions about such a task ;].

Comment: If it's somewhere, it's probably here: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi. But does pylint do this job?

Comment: Can you not ask this developer you have met what she was using?

Comment: @lunaryorn, Well if recover his email maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For automatic checking using imported modules you need install *flycheck* and *python-mode*, and later execute command `flycheck-verify-setup`.

[image: flycheck-verify-setup (all installed and founded)]

Later you must install python packages, for example, pep8, pylint, flake8 and other. Install him with pip on system side (**recommended**) or in your virtual environment.

[image: Flycheck highlight unused imported module]

Comment: Ok I kind of forgot this question of mine. I am now using `flake8` for months and it fills this very purpose. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to make it work so when you reference attributes of modules that are imported it will highlight if the attribute does not exist or its usage doesn't fit its definition?  This is the last thing preventing me from getting completely off a graphical IDE.

Answer (score 4):

You can get automatic python syntax checking (including unused imports) by installing [flycheck](https://github.com/lunaryorn/flycheck)

Comment: Please note that installing Flycheck alone is not sufficient.  You will also need a syntax checking tool.  With regards to Python, you need either Pylint or Flake8.  I recommend the latter.

Answer (score 2):

[ropemacs](http://rope.sourceforge.net/ropemacs.html) can (among other things) organize imports (remove duplicated and unused imports, sort them,...).

I am not sure if unused imports are highlighted, but it definitely helps with that.

Also, since pyflakes detect unused imports, probably something like [flymake-python-pyflakes](https://github.com/purcell/flymake-python-pyflakes) might do the highlighting part (in addition to other goodies)